# Modify Controller To Work With Heroku's Postgres DB

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

My album review app has a model for the reviews called Pins, which has the attributes artist, album (the title), and image. (image is the album cover art, which is a paperclip attachment)

I am generating a list of every artist that has been reviewed on the site, along with each album from that artist. Here is my code, which works fine on my local DB:

Pin.rb Model:

```
class Pin < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :description, :image, :image_remote_url, :artist, :album, :date, :rank, :video, :video_html, :rating, :year, :title, :tag_list

  has_attached_file :image, styles: { :medium => "320x240>", :small => "200x200>" }
  validates :description, presence: true
  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :artist, presence: true
  validates :album, presence: true
  validates :year, presence: true
  validates :rating, presence: true
  validates_attachment :image, presence: true,
                                                     content_type: { content_type: ['image/jpeg', 'image/jpg', 'image/gif', 'image/png'] }, 
                                                     size: { less_than: 5.megabytes }
  has_many :videos
end
```

The Schema for Pins:

```
create_table "pins", force: true do |t|
    t.text     "description",        limit: 255
    t.datetime "created_at",                     null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                     null: false
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.string   "image_file_name"
    t.string   "image_content_type"
    t.integer  "image_file_size"
    t.datetime "image_updated_at"
    t.string   "image_remote_url"
    t.string   "artist"
    t.string   "album"
    t.integer  "date"
    t.integer  "rank"
    t.string   "video_html"
    t.string   "video"
    t.string   "rating"
    t.string   "year"
    t.string   "title"
  end
```

Pins Controller:

```
def artists
  @pin_albums = Pin.group(:album).order('artist') 
end
```

Artists Page View:

```
<div class="artist_list">
  <% last_artist ||= nil %>
  <table id="artist">
      <tr>
        <th>Artist</th>
        <th></th>
        <th>Album</th>
      </tr>
    <% @pin_artists.each do |pin| %>  
        <tr>
          <td><%= (last_artist == pin.artist)  ?  ''   :   pin.artist %></td>
          <td><%= image_tag(pin.image) %></td>
          <td><%= link_to pin.album, copy_pin_path(pin) %></td>
        </tr>      
    <% last_artist = pin.artist %>     
    <% end %>
  </table>
</div>
```

That gives me an output that looks like this:

[image]

After pushing to Heroku I got the following error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "pins.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

After Googling I found that the .group method won't work on Postgres DB, so I need to use a Select method. I have come up with this:

Pins Controller:

```
@pin_artists = Pin.select(:album, :artist).distinct.order('artist')
```

This builds the table out correctly for the most part, but I am not able to attach the album art. When I try to add :image to teh select method above I get:

```
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: image: SELECT DISTINCT "pins"."album", "pins"."artist", image FROM "pins"   ORDER BY artist
```

How do I properly code my controller so that I can call pin.image in my view?

EDIT:

The answer that I accepted below was what I was looking for, but I still needed to change some things in my view. Here is the final version which shows the artist only once and each of their albums only once.

Controller:

```
@pin_albums = Pin.all.order(:artist).group_by(&:artist)
```

View:

```
<table id="artist">
<% last_artist ||= nil %>
<% last_album ||= nil %>
<% @pin_albums.each do |artist, pins| %>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" class="artist-name"><%= (last_artist == artist)  ?  ''   :   artist %></td> 
  </tr>  
  <% pins.each do |pin| %>
    <% if last_album != pin.album %> 
      <tr>
        <td><%= link_to image_tag(pin.image), pin %></td>
        <td><%= link_to pin.album, copy_pin_path(pin) %></td>
      </tr> 
      <% last_album = pin.album %>
    <% end %>   
  <% end %>
  <% last_artist = artist %>         
<% end %>
```

Comment: My answer is pretty thin on details, but if you can post your relevant models code it would help. Also What are the fields for each table?

Comment: Thanks. I added the model and Schema. There is only one model involved, the Pins model. Each pin has an artist, album, and image. I'm gathering all of the artists represented on the site and their respective albums, then listing them in a table. (without duplicating them of course)

Comment: The simple answer is you don't have an 'image' column. Which is true. Paperclip is doing that magic for you. You could add  `image_remote_url` to the columns being selected, then just reference it as the URL in the view code. I'm thinking that's not desirable as you won't get true thumbnails? The answer below returns each pin as a complete object, so any methods provided by Paperclip should work in the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using Postgres on my dev machine and on Heroku. I find `.group` a pain in many instances, probably because I don't get what it's really doing under the hood. I use `group_by`, **edit** I was able to add the order before the group by. My own problems with ordering came from some joining issues.

You could use:

```
def artists
  @pin_albums = Pin.all.order(:artist).group_by(&:album) 
end
```

I have used this method successfully. It will return a hash in the format of:

```
@pin_albums = {"album1" => [#<pin1...>, #<pin2...], "album2" => [#<pin3..>...}
```

Looking at your output, maybe it should be

```
@pin_albums = Pin.all.order(:artist).group_by(&:artist)
```

That way your hash is

```
{"artist1" => [#<pin1.... ], "artist2" => [....]}
```

Then it would be easy to manipulate that data into the table format you've shown.

You can do something like this much in the same way you are using your current view code, I've left out the html and .erb for brevity:

```
last_artist ||= nil

@pin_albums.each do |artist,pins|
  pins.each do |pin| 
    (last_artist == artist)  ?  ''   :   artist
    image_tag(pin.image)
    link_to pin.album, copy_pin_path(pin)
  end
  last_artist = artist
end
```

See, you are just using a nested loop, the pins are looped through for each artist. It also gives you a nice hash as the data structure that could be easily converted to json if needed in the future.

Comment: I see that each artist is returned with an array of all of their pins. How do I access that info since I can't use my current code?

Comment: Added the structure for the view code. Really it's exactly what you had except it's got a nested loop inside for the pins since you are iterating through a hash where the keys are strings and the values are arrays.

Comment: Ok, we're getting close! That works on Heroku, but it lists every pin on the entire site. My original controller code above groups all pins with the same album title together and then in my view I list each artist and their albums. My view code also only lists the artist once.

Comment: Not sure how you've fit the above code into your view. Do you have this on github? It would make it easy to see the entire code. The listing of the artist once would be a function of the ternary statement you used previously. From the small example you gave in the original post it's hard to tell how you've grouped it since no album repeats. If you do want to group by album instead of artist use the first version of the query I posted. I missed the `DISTINCT` part of your query. That should be easy to remedy.

Comment: Yes, try the first query I gave, where grouped by album. That way the key is the album and the group_by automatically gives you `DISTINCT` based on album rather than artist.

Comment: Ok, so the second option was good. I solved the issue with it listing every pin by adding code to the view so that it wouldn't show the album if it had already showed it. I'll add it to the question so that it's clear in case anyone else could use the info. Thanks for the help!